# How to change the default required select option field message using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the default Message of a required select option field. Its a variation of WooCommerce's product. I added the property dynamically and try to change the message my bellow code able to change the message but it not works . It always appearing no matter if there is a selected value or not.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/tbnry7qd/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="color" class="" name="attribute_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_color">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
     <option value="White" class="attached enabled">White</option>
     <option value="Black" class="attached enabled">Black</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('select#color').prop('required', true);
  if( !$('select#color').has('value').length > 0 ) {
    $('select#color').attr("oninvalid", "this.setCustomValidity('Please select a color')");
  }else{
     $('select#color').removeAttr("oninvalid", "this.setCustomValidity('Please select a color')");
  }
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/tbnry7qd/)

[image: Required error message]

Comment: when you want this functionality ? while adding data or on `load` event ?

Comment: First after `load` the `required` and `the message` should  work and when the select field change or it has a value the message should gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the msdn docs:

> Constraint API's element.setCustomValidity()
>   The element.setCustomValidity(error) method is used to set a custom error message to be displayed when a form is submitted. The method works by taking a string parameter error. If error is a non-empty string, the method assumes validation was unsuccessful and displays error as an error message. If error is an empty string, the element is considered validated and resets the error message.

It means that once you `setCustomValidity` error the input will be considered as invalid till you wont reset it by passing empty string.

What I did below is checking when select event happened and check if select has value if it doesn't then set error if it has then reset error.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbnry7qd/4/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var selectColor = $('select#color');
  selectColor.prop('required', true);
  /* Check if there is no selected value on ready if not mark select as invalid */
  if(!selectColor.val()){
       selectColor[0].setCustomValidity('Please select a color');  
  }
  /* Do the same check when select value changed */
  selectColor.on('change', function(){      
    if(!selectColor.val()){
        selectColor[0].setCustomValidity('Please select a color');
    }else{      
        selectColor[0].setCustomValidity('');
    }    
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you give me a WordPress version of your code?

Comment: @Firefog if element selector is the same it should work regardless if it is or it is not a wordpress.

Comment: But wordpress declare `jquery` instead of `$` please check https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Firefog Ok, i changed it it should work it is done that way to prevent conflicts between various JS libraries.

Comment: I think we should set `setTimeout` function to check the select event :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('select#color').on('invalid', function () {
    return this.setCustomValidity('Please select a color.');
}).on('change', function () {
    return this.setCustomValidity('');
});
```